# Illegal instruction when import tensorflow in Python

Tags: python, linux, tensorflow, centos

I am trying to run python program in shell, CentOS 7.0 x64, on VPS

python3 version is 3.6.4

pip3 version is 9.0.1

when I use `pip3 freeze` it has `tensorflow==1.6.0`

The first line of `xx.py` is `import tensorflow`

whether I use `python3 xx.py` or type `import tensorflow` in python3 shell, it turns out to be `Illegal instruction`

Besides, any other import like `import numpy`, `import sklearn` function well, nothing wrong with them

How to solve this?

Comment: Try using a virtualenv.

Comment: Can you import any order library besides tensorflow to see if the problem is with your python 3.6 installation in general or with tensorflow? This sounds like a python installation problem and not just virtual environment or tensorflow

Comment: @AhmedS yes I have imported others, all are ok except tensorflow. e.g. `sklearn, scipy, pandas` all function well

Comment: @sytech I do not understand why the virtual python environment will help. Since this is not a version conflict. Could you please let me know the possible reason?

Comment: @Litchy -- It's anecdotal, but I had the same error with certain packages on Mac OS/Python3.6 but the problem went away in a virtualenv, for reasons unknown to me at this time.

Comment: @sytech haha I tried and I still have the same problem. I guess your problem is that your previous package does not match the tensorflow dependencies, like numpy, etc. But mine, ..., I still do not know how to solve it T T

Answer (score 4):

TensorFlow 1.6 started using AVX feature of modern CPUs:
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/releases/tag/v1.6.0

Downgrade to 1.5:
`pip install tensorflow==1.5`