Illegal instruction (core dumped) import keras
If I try to do 'import keras', it gives core dump.
python3 -c 'import keras; print(keras.__version__)'
Illegal instruction (core dumped)

or
python3 test.py
Illegal instruction (core dumped)

I tried to uninstall and re-install keras, but no luck. Current version is :
pip3  list | grep keras
keras                        2.13.1  

I am running Virtual Machine, CPU Architecture: x86_64
How to solve this ?
Note: Here is the CPU details where I am running the Linux.
CPU family:                           6
Model:                                140
Model name:                           11th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-1165G7 @ 2.80GHz
Stepping:                             1
CPU MHz:                              2803.198 


I would guess that virtual machine CPU doesn't support some of the instructions required by that version of Keras (e.g. some SSE instructions).

How old is your system? Check out https://stackoverflow.com/a/78253807/218663 and potentially https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51599488/illegal-instruction-4-error-when-running-any-tensorflow-program

As suggested in the comment section, the content of '/var/log/syslog' suggest that some kernel trap occurred due to invalid opcode when tried to 'import keras'.
Nov 27 17:30:01 lpk-ee213423-vm CRON[8876]: (root) CMD ([ -x /etc/init.d/anacron ] && if [ ! -d /run/systemd/system ]; then /usr/sbin/invoke-rc.d anacron start >/dev/null; fi)
Nov 27 17:30:35 lpk-ee213423-vm kernel: [16051.740500] traps: python3[8877] trap invalid opcode ip:7fcbd49ecdea sp:7ffcaaf37960 error:0 in libtensorflow_framework.so.2[7fcbd3ab4000+12d8000]
python


Please try again by installing the latest keras version using below command
pip install -U Keras
You can follow the official Tensorflow install doc for more details on the installation steps.
